# R can't find function scale_colour_tableau

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

While I run my App, R shows me could not find funtion `scale_colour_tableau`.

I've installed ggplot2 and shiny via R studio.

The errors occupied on server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$exPlot<-renderPlot({

ggplot(data=MP,aes(x=year,y=Gprice,fill=Cprice,xmax=100,ymax=100))+geom_bar(width=1,stat="identity")+ggtitle(expression(atop("Market Analysis",atop("")))) +theme(plot.title=element_text(size=20)) +theme_gray()+scale_colour_tableau()}, height = 600, width = 900)



output$exPlot2<-renderPlot({

ggplot(data=PI,aes(x=Type,y=DemandIndex,fill=Type,xmax=100,ymax=100))+geom_bar(width=1,stat="identity")+coord_polar(theta = "x")+ggtitle(expression(atop("Radar Analysis",atop("let’s have fun"))))+theme(plot.title=element_text(size=20))+theme_gray()+scale_colour_tableau()}, height = 600, width = 900)  

  })
```

R studio version is 0.99.902

R version is 3.3.0

Comment: `scale_colour_tableau` is not a `ggplot2` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(ggthemes)
```